# How to get image label by product id in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get image label by product id in magento 1?

I want get label image, i tryed this code but it get not all product collection, some missing. Please help me

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$customimg = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('file',$product->getData('image'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php 
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','black')->getFile();  
?>
```

from

> list.phtml

Hope this will help you..!